# MyIbatis-Spring Transaction closeSession

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ibatis

When I use MyIbatis with spring transaction, using the Annotation driven declarative method, do I have do bother manage the session.

Without the transaction I usually do like this:

```
public int insertPnt(Movimenti value) {
    try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
    for (Movimenti value : values) {
        session.insert(
                    "com.sirio.cisl.dal.MovimentiMapper.insertSelective",
                    value);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error inserting movimenti "+user+" anno "+anno+" "+ e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

but from MyIbatis-Spring documentation I read

> MyBatis SqlSession provides you with specific methods to handle
>   transactions programmatically. ...........
>   . That means that Spring will always handle your
>   transactions.
>   You cannot call SqlSession.commit(), SqlSession.rollback() or
>   SqlSession.close() over a Spring managed SqlSession.

So I wandering if I'm doing correct when I just adding the `@Transaction` annotation (and the `<tx:annotation-driven>` config) to the method.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public int insertPnt(Movimenti value) {
    try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {

    ..............

}
```

Does the transaction manager take care of the session resourse? Or I have to remove the `try-catch` clause.

Thk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the same question to the MyIbatis-user group [see](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mybatis-user/j24VIbkvKfU). The response was useful:

> To use MyBatis you need either an SqlSesion or a Mapper interface.
>   With "classic" MyBatis you get the sessions out of an
>   SqlSessionFactory but when using Spring this changes.

So I follow the example of the [documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/spring/sqlsession.html):
I inject the Service class with a sqlSessionTemplate that internally takes care of opening and close the session.

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:myibatis.xml"/>
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:mappers/*.xml" />
</bean>


<bean id="asTableService" class="com.sirio.cisl.dal.AsTableService">
    <property name="session" ref="sqlSession" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate" destroy-method="clearCache">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
  <constructor-arg index="1" value="BATCH" />
</bean>
```

Then I can use the @Transactional annotation :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public int insertPnt(Movimenti value) {
      session.create(......)
 }
```

Davide